# Issue with PyTorch Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to run the GFTE github lab code here:
https://github.com/Irene323/GFTE.git

I downloaded the SciTSR dataset and modified root_path on line 60 and line 62, however when trying to run dataset1.py, it gives the following error:

```
train_dataset = ScitsrDataset(root_path)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ScitsrDataset with abstract method len
```

I suspect it is due to an issue with I'm using the latest PyTorch version, when I looked into ScitsrDataset, it shows that **len** function is defined. Can anyone point out what changes are needed to make this code run?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)